# Using join method dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a reference array based on each English alphabet index:

```
let reference = [0, 2, 3];
```

and an array of words or even phrases:

```
let words = ["A", "C", "D"];
```

And I want to join each word from `words array` to create a simple sentence but considering the gaps between words ( whenever the values in the reference array aren't consecutive numbers! ), so the desired output would be :

```
A...C D // gaps filled with three dots
```

The problem is I can't find a solution to use `join()` method to do it!

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because `join` just joins, it doesn't know anything about non-joining logic. You'll likely need to code this yourself; twisting `join` to do anything like this would be more confusing than just writing it.

Comment: I didn't understand why did you include the reference array when it's of no use to the question. You can use words.join("...")

Comment: You want `...` whenever the values in the reference array aren't consecutive numbers?

Comment: @mAhMoUdDaFeR That will create `A...C...D`, not `A...C D`

Comment: Wait then when do you want to have the three dots, is only between the first 2 letters or?

Comment: Based on the reference array u would've to come up with own logic (like difference between prev-curr index > 1) something like that and then concat. `join` wouldn't work here.

Comment: @Barmar exactly...

Comment: I've included the reference array because maybe the words array is filled with phrases and not only alphabets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new array from `words` based on the gaps in `reference` and then join:

```js
let reference = [0, 2, 3];
let words = ["A", "C", "D"];

let res = [];
reference.forEach((n, i) => {
  if (n - reference[i - 1] >= 2) res.push('...', words[i]);
  else res.push(words[i]);
});

console.log(res.join(' '));
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?!

Comment: Because it doesn't do what you specified you wanted? (Although a simple global substitution would fix that.)

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array by checking the delta of the last value and the actual value.

```js
var reference = [0, 2, 3],
    result = reference.reduce((r, v, i, { [i - 1]: last }) =>
        r + (r && (i && v - last > 1 ? '...' : ' ')) + (v + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase(), '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Where is the words array :)

Comment: do you need both? i thought, the numbers represents the letters?

Answer (score 1):

An approach of comparing **`reference`** array values each time while iterating on the actual **`words`** array:

```js
let reference = [0, 2, 3, 4, 7];

let words = ["A", "C", "D", "E", "H"];
let prev = 0;
let joined = words[prev];
for (let i = 1, l = words.length; i < l; ++i) {
  const diff = reference[i] - reference[prev];
  if (diff > 1) {
    joined += "..." + words[i];
  } else {
    joined += " " + words[i];
  }

  prev = i;
}

//Since CDE ar continuous and AC and EH are not
console.info(joined);
```